# PHP getOffset() without Datetime() Class

Tags: php, datetime

I have a quick question.

The following code works nicely on my localhost

however after i upload to the server it failed reason due to the PHP version on server was not updated, and it was the DateTime class. It required 5.2 above

Just wondering if there is any alternative to the getOffset()?

this bit: 
**$now = new DateTime();
$mins = $now->getOffset() / 60;**

```
$now = new DateTime();
$mins = $now->getOffset() / 60;
$sgn = ($mins < 0 ? -1 : 1);
$mins = abs($mins);
$hrs = floor($mins / 60);
$mins -= $hrs * 60;
$offset = sprintf('%+d:%02d', $hrs*$sgn, $mins);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the server runs PHP < 5.2 then the admin should be offered a chance to repent their sins.

Comment: I don't need to remember what the options were **7 years ago**, so I don't remember them. But just guessing: the only thing you can do is write your own timezone code from scratch. Did so once; it wasn't fun.

Comment: @Jon Thanks Joh ok contact server admin then -__-